# execl("/bin/bash","bash","-l","-c","env",NULL), what's wrong?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I want to use `execl("/bin/bash","bash","-l","-c","env",NULL)` to get the environment variables,the reason why I use parameter `"-l"` is that I needn't source `"/etc/profile"`,`"~/.bash_login"` and so on. But when I run it, the program is suspended and I have to use ctrl+c or ctrl+d to stop it? Can you tell me how to modify it?

The code is shown as follows,getPtrArray is used to change one-dimensional array to two-dimensional array.

```
int pid;
int fd[2];
char buffer[10000];
char** envi;
int res=pipe(fd);
//create a child process to get environment variable
if((pid=fork())==0){
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    struct passwd *pw=getpwnam("hgchen");
    char *shell_type=pw->pw_shell;
    if(execl("/bin/bash","bash","-l","-c","env",(char*)0)<0){
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    exit(0);     
}
// main process
else{
    wait(NULL);
    close(fd[1]);
    int nbytes=read(fd[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    envi=getPtrArray(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the getenv() function?

Comment: Yes,I also know that environ can get the environment variables. Because the execl is executed in my child process, and when the users is different,their shell type may be differnet too. So I have to source different files when the shell type is different. In order to simpify it，I use "-l" to simulate a login shell.

Comment: When you run it how? Can you share the shortest C program which fails in the way you describe? Do you see the output from env?

Comment: You probably also know that exec, if successful, does not return. Are you running this in a subprocess? Can you show the process handling code?

Comment: `bash` is blocking on *standard output*. You create a pipe, but don't read from that pipe in the parent process, instead wait for the child to exit. The child in turn is blocked on writing to the pipe before it will exit. Therefore, deadlock.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to modify my program?

Comment: Done; I rewrote my answer to show an example solution.

Comment: There's several things wrong here. Consider using `posix_spawn` instead. It's apparently missing in uclibc though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit note: This is a full rewrite of the original example code, since the OP posted the code and I realized it causes `bash` to block on *standard output* instead of input as I originally thought. The reason is `bash` output is redirected to a pipe, with nothing reading from the pipe until the child exits.

Before you `execl()`, reopen `STDIN_FILENO` from `/dev/null`, and `STDERR_FILENO` to `/dev/null`. When `STDOUT_FILENO` (standard output) is redirected to a pipe, you cannot just `wait()` for the child to exit: you must actively read from the pipe while the child process runs.

Consider this example program. It takes one command-line parameter, the user name. (Without any parameters or just `-h` or `--help` it outputs short usage information.)

It obtains the `struct passwd` corresponding to that user name, creating a duplicate of the path to the user shell stored in that structure. It forks a child process, executing `path-to-shell shell-name -c env` in the child process, capturing the output to a dynamically allocated array (using the `execute()` function). The main then just writes the output to original standard output, for simplicity. You can omit the final `while () { ... }` loop to see that the output is really captured to the dynamically allocated array.

Note that I haven't actually verified that *all* shells support the `-c` syntax. I do know that `bash`, `sh` (original Bourne shells), `dash` (a POSIX shell), `tcsh`, and `zsh` all do -- covering all shells that are in my `/etc/shells`, i.e. allowed shells file --, so it *should* work in practice; I just cannot guarantee it.

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Open file or device to the specified descriptor.
 * Will never create files.
 * Returns 0 if success, errno otherwise.
*/
static int reopen(const int descriptor, const char *const path, const int flags)
{
    int result, fd;

    if (descriptor == -1)
        return errno = EBADF;
    if (!path || !*path || flags & O_CREAT)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    do {
        fd = open(path, flags);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1)
        return errno;

    if (fd == descriptor)
        return errno = 0;

    do {
        result = dup2(fd, descriptor);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1)
        return errno;

    do {
        result = close(fd);
    } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (result == -1)
        return errno;

    return errno = 0;
}

/* Helper function: Close descriptor keeping errno unchanged.
 * Returns 0 if success, errno.h error code otherwise.
*/
static int closefd(const int descriptor)
{
    if (descriptor != -1) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;
        int       result;
        do {
            result = close(descriptor);
        } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (result == -1)
            result = errno;
        else
            result = 0;
        errno = saved_errno;
        return result;
    } else
        return EBADF;
}

/* Execute a command in a child process, capturing the output.
 * Standard input and error are redirected to /dev/null.
 * Returns zero if success, errno error code otherwise.
*/
int execute(const char *const cmdpath,
            const char *const args[],
            char      **const dataptr,
            size_t     *const sizeptr,
            size_t     *const lenptr,
            int        *const statusptr)
{
    pid_t   child, p;
    int     out[2], result, *childstatus;
    char   *data;
    size_t  size, used = 0;
    ssize_t bytes;

    if (!cmdpath || !*cmdpath || !args || !args[0] || !dataptr || !sizeptr || !lenptr)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    /* Create the standard output pipe. */
    if (pipe(out))
        return errno;

    /* Fork the child process. */
    child = fork();
    if (child == (pid_t)-1) {
        closefd(out[0]);
        closefd(out[1]);
        return errno;
    }

    if (!child) {
        /*
         * Child process.
        */
        closefd(STDIN_FILENO);
        closefd(STDOUT_FILENO);
        closefd(STDERR_FILENO);
        closefd(out[0]);

        /* Redirect standard output to the pipe. */
        if (out[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {
            do {
                result = dup2(out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            } while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);
            if (result == -1)
                _exit(127);
            closefd(out[1]);
        }

        /* Open standard input from /dev/null. */
        if (reopen(STDIN_FILENO, "/dev/null", O_RDONLY))
            _exit(127);

        /* Open standard error to /dev/null. */
        if (reopen(STDERR_FILENO, "/dev/null", O_WRONLY))
            _exit(127);

        /* Execute the specified command. */
        execv(cmdpath, (char **)args);

        /* Failed. */
        _exit(127);
    }

    /*
     * Parent process.
    */

    closefd(out[1]);

    if (*sizeptr > 0) {
        data = *dataptr;
        size = *sizeptr;
    } else {
        data = *dataptr = NULL;
        size = *sizeptr = 0;
    }

    while (1) {

        /* Grow data array if needed. */
        if (used >= size) {
            size = (used | 32767) + 32769;
            data = realloc(data, size);
            if (!data) {
                kill(child, SIGTERM);
                do {
                    p = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
                } while (p == (pid_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
                return errno = ENOMEM;
            }
            *dataptr = data;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        /* Read more data. */
        do {
            bytes = read(out[0], data + used, size - used);
        } while (bytes == (ssize_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (bytes > (ssize_t)0)
            used += (size_t)bytes;
        else
        if (bytes == (ssize_t)0)
            break; /* All read (end of input) */
        else {
            const int retval = (bytes == (ssize_t)-1) ? errno : EIO;
            kill(child, SIGTERM);
            do {
                p = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
            } while (p == (pid_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
            return errno = retval;
        }
    }

    /* We need to add the final '\0', which might not fit. */
    if (used + 1 >= size) {
        size = used + 1;
        data = realloc(data, size);
        if (!data) {
            kill(child, SIGTERM);
            do {
                p = waitpid(child, NULL, 0);
            } while (p == (pid_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
            return errno = ENOMEM;
        }
        *dataptr = data;
        *sizeptr = size;
    }

    data[used] = '\0';
    if (lenptr)
        *lenptr = used;

    /* Reap the child process. */
    if (statusptr)
        childstatus = statusptr;
    else
        childstatus = &result;
    do {
        p = waitpid(child, childstatus, 0);
    } while (p == (pid_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (p == (pid_t)-1)
        return errno;

    /* Success. */
    return errno = 0;
}

/* A helper to write to standard error. Errno is kept unchanged.
 * Returns zero if success, errno error code otherwise.
 * Async-signal safe, in case you wish to use this safely in a signal handler.
*/
static int wrerr(const char *const message)
{
    if (message && *message) {
        const int   saved_errno = errno;
        const char *p = message;
        const char *q = message;
        ssize_t     n;

        /* q = message + strlen(message), except that strlen()
         * is not an async-signal safe function. */
        while (*q)
            q++;

        while (p < q) {
            n = write(STDERR_FILENO, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
                errno = saved_errno;
                return EIO;
            } else
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                const int retval = errno;
                errno = saved_errno;
                return retval;
            }
        }

        errno = saved_errno;
        return 0;
    } else
        return 0;
}

const char *basename_of(const char *const string)
{
    const char *r;

    if (!string)
        return NULL;

    r = strrchr(string, '/');
    if (r && r[1])
        return r + 1;

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct passwd *pw;
    char          *shell;
    const char    *args[4];
    char          *data = NULL;
    size_t         size = 0;
    size_t         used = 0;
    int            status;

    if (argc != 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        wrerr("\n");
        wrerr("Usage: "); wrerr(argv[0]); wrerr(" [ -h | --help ]\n");
        wrerr("       "); wrerr(argv[0]); wrerr(" USERNAME\n");
        wrerr("\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pw = getpwnam(argv[1]);
    if (!pw) {
        wrerr(argv[1]);
        wrerr(": ");
        wrerr(strerror(errno));
        wrerr(".\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (pw->pw_shell && pw->pw_shell[0] == '/')
        shell = strdup(pw->pw_shell);
    else
        shell = strdup("/bin/sh");
    args[0] = basename_of(shell);
    if (!args[0]) {
        wrerr(argv[1]);
        wrerr(": User has invalid shell, '");
        wrerr(shell);
        wrerr("'.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    args[1] = "-c";
    args[2] = "env";
    args[3] = NULL;

    if (execute(shell, args, &data, &size, &used, &status)) {
        wrerr("Failed to execute ");
        wrerr(shell);
        wrerr(": ");
        wrerr(strerror(errno));
        wrerr(".\n");
        return 1;
    }

    free(shell);

    /* Dump environment to standard output. */
    {
        const char       *p = data;
        const char *const q = data + used;
        ssize_t           n;

        while (p < q) {
            n = write(STDOUT_FILENO, p, (size_t)(q - p));
            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                p += n;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
                wrerr("Error writing to standard output.\n");
                return 1;
            } else
            if (errno != EINTR) {
                wrerr("standard output: ");
                wrerr(strerror(errno));
                wrerr(".\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    free(data);
    data = NULL;
    size = 0;
    used = 0;

    /* All done. */
    return 0;
}
```

This is much lower-level code than is really necessary (or preferred); you can do the same using `popen()` and other `stdio.h` I/O functions.

(I avoided those only to make this more interesting to myself.)

The `wrerr()` is just a helper function I like to use, as unlike `fprintf()`/`printf()`/`perror()`, it is async-signal safe and ignores signal deliveries (`errno==EINTR`).  Here, it is *not* needed, and you could use e.g. `fprintf()` just as well. (Unlike just about every example you can see on the net, `printf()` et al. are not supposed to work in signal handlers. They usually do work, but there are absolutely no guarantees. `wrerr()` will work, as it is POSIX compliant.)

I also included full error checking. Some of the error cases are impossible to hit without a kernel bug, but I prefer to have them anyway. You really *do want* them in the cases where you do hit a bug, be it in your own code or elsewhere.

In the error cases I don't bother to free dynamically allocated memory (although I could have), since the kernel will always take care of that automatically. The program does, however, release all dynamically allocated memory before returning from `main()` if no errors occur.

Questions?

Comment: Yes，I need an example.Thanks.

Comment: Why should bash wait for stdin if there are cmdline arguments which denote the command to be executed?

Comment: @glgl: Well, perhaps not `bash` itself (it might, but it should be a bug then), but one of the profile scripts.

Comment: @glgl: Nope, now that I saw the actual source code, it is blocking on *standard output*.

Comment: That's alot of source code to do something so simple... good luck maintaining that.

Comment: @trojanfoe: There are a few cases where `stdio.h` I/O is unsuitable. The OP's question is not one of them, true. However, I did not treat the question as *"what is the best way to get the environment variables defined for a specific user"*, but more as an exercise in low-level I/O. Therefore, the "good luck maintaining that" comment is both unsuitable, and just makes you look butthurt. Don't be, your answer is just as valuable as mine, at least in my opinion.

Comment: Well I don't know what a "butthurt" is, but I don't think SO answers are the place for exercising your desire to test things out.  The "good luck" message is entirely appropriate given the amount of code you have provided for something so simple.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Not my desire for testing, OP's. Testing is a big part of learning, and I tried to help the OP to learn. Based on OP's response, I think it did help.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it's much easier to use [`popen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).

This is tested and working (under OSX, not Linux):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    char line[1024];
    FILE *pipefp = popen("/bin/bash -l -c env", "r");
    if (pipefp) {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), pipefp)) {
            // Note: line contains newline
            printf("%s", line);
        }
        pclose(pipefp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to find what's causing your command to suspend add "-x" option. And this code work for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int r = execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-x", "-l", "-c", "env", NULL);
    printf("r: %d\n", r); /* This should not be printed or else execl has errors. */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `wait` in the parent is wrong. You must first *read* the output from the shall and *then* wait for it. As already explained in the comment, the shell is waiting for you to read the output and you are waiting for the shell to exit, therefore you deadlocked.

You need to move the `wait` *after* the `read`.